# ¿Cómo abrir ventana modal al pasar mouse sobre elemento HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Tengo una ventana modal (display: none) y nesecito mostrarla al pasar el mouse sobre una etiqueta.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
            <div class="modalTipo" id="loginModal" >
                <div class="modal-content2">
                    <div class="row">
                    
                           <table style="background-color:#F3F3F3;color:green;">
                               <tr>    
                                    <td class="col-md-4" style="background-color:#F3F3F3;color:green"> <span> AfirmeNet </span> </td>
                                    <td> <input type="radio" id="rPersonas"></td> 
                                    <td><label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">Personas</label></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><input type="radio" id="rEmpresas" > </td>
                                    <td><label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">Empresas </label> </td>
                               </tr>

                               <tr>    
                                   <td class="col-md-4" style="background-color:#F3F3F3;color:green"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
                                   <td colspan="2"><input type="text" placeholder="Personas" /></td>
                                   <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>                        
                                   <td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-success" /></td>
                               </tr>

                           </table>
      
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
function MostrarLoginModal() {
    $('#loginModal').show();
}
```

Comment: el método onHover creo te podría servir

Comment: Tienes que usar el evento `hover` para realizar lo que quieres, algo así `$(element).hover(function(e) {  -- aquí va el código -- })`

Answer (score 2):

El evento que nesecitaba es MouseOver.

Agregue estas lineas a mi codigo JQuery:

```
$("#_menu").mouseover(function () {
    $('#loginModal').show();
});
```